# Trigger click event to hidden row in DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I use last version of DataTable, and after my page is loaded, I need to trigger an event on a row which belongs to page 2 (from DataTable javascript pagination).

I use this code :

```
var $tableSpendings = $('#table-main');
var table = $tableSpendings.DataTable({ ... });

// returns element if element is on page 1, null if not on page 1
// console.log($tableSpendings.find('.btn-edit-spending-3000'));

$tableSpendings.find('.btn-edit-spending-3000')
         .addClass('test')
         .trigger('click');
```

It works if the element is on the page 1 (from DataTable javascript pagination), but not if the element is not on page 1. It's like the element is hidden and not accessible.

I tried many selectors, but my element on page 2 (or more) is never selected. How can I select an element hidden by this javascript pagination ?

Here is a Fiddle of my problem : https://jsfiddle.net/applyss/p9swazn5/6/

Comment: Have you researched the documentation of DataTable for a method that triggers every time the plugin paints data? If you inspect the HTML rows... do you see the element in *page 2*? Is it present in DOM?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use initComplete event now, I will check. But for me, since the elements are in the DOM, it should not cause any issue ?

Comment: If the element is not present in the DOM or if you trigger your action *before* DataTable finishes its stuff, `.find()` will not return much...

Comment: Why ? it's jquery selection. I use classic HTML to fill my table, so all elements are in the DOM. I checked to use the initComplete function, but since I use sync data, it fires before if call my trigger

Comment: A quick look at the documentation lead me to the `draw` event, which triggers once dataTables  - well, finishes drawing.

Comment: Inside the `draw` callback do a `console.log($tableSpendings.find('.btn-edit-spending-3000').length)` and if you get `1` you're good to go. https://datatables.net/manual/events

Comment: I added a fiddle of my problem. Even with the event, it doesn't add the class to the row (search for "Tiger")

Comment: The fiddle you posted has nothing to do with your code in question.

Comment: I updated the fiddle, the .to-color elements are not colored on the DOM ready, but they are if you click on the button

Comment: When you change the pagination change add or remove class condition based